# How to implement Google Indoor Map with Titanium SDK?

Tags: google-maps, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, google-indoor-maps

How to implement Google Indoor Map with Titanium SDK?
I need to show indoor maps for iOS and Android application.

There is not so much stuff available on this. 
I am newbie in Titanium.  Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Reading https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/, it looks like this is something you arrange with Google and then it just appears on Google Maps? You should be able to use http://gitt.io/component/ti.googlemaps on iOS and https://appcelerator.github.io/appc-docs/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map on Android then.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts, but this is more likely Marking any places while we need to show Indoor maps ? Any other suggestion ?

Comment: At https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/ it says it's also available via the Google Maps API for apps.